# How to bundle Go and its asset files into WASM?

Tags: go, webassembly

I have a Go program that uses some json files (like 15) for data. I want to compile it into a WebAssembly file.

How can I do this?

Note: I know I can just pass those json values from my JS code to WASM, but I don't want that if I can effectively bundle them with WASM.

EDIT: lastly we tried https://pkg.go.dev/embed as [NobbyNobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4478375/nobbynobbs) mentioned, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: did you try [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed)?

Comment: I just tried embed, it's working

Answer (score 1):

if you want to bundle any type of **file/directory** with compiled code (*like binary/wasm*) , there is a awesome Golang library [packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr) . It's easy to use and when you compile the source code to binary or webassembly packr  loads the file/directory and works the same way as before.

here i am using ***`main.go`*** in the root directory of the project. and a directory to store json data (like ***`/jsondata/mydata.json`***)

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/packr/v2"
)

func main() {
    box := packr.New("myBox", "./jsondata")

    s, err := box.FindString("mydata.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(" ~ file: main.go ~ line 14 ~ funcmain ~ err : ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

#### */jsondata/mydata.json*

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S"
        }
    }
}
```

than run the code using `go run main.go`.
if you compiled it to the binary the ***json*** file ships with the binary code
`go build main.go`

if you compiled it to the ***wasm*** , the folder will behave the same way
`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm main.go`

### Second method (Using "embed")

use `embed` library from standard library .

here i am using ***`main.go`*** in the root directory of the project. and creating a file in same directory (like ***`/sample.json`***)

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
  "embed"
)

//go:embed sample.json
var f embed.FS

func main(){
data, _ := f.ReadFile("sample.json")
print(string(data))

}
```

#### */sample.json*

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S"
        }
    }
}
```

than run the code using `go run main.go`.
if you compiled it to the binary the ***json*** file ships with the binary code
`go build main.go`

if you compiled it to the ***wasm*** , the folder will behave the same way
`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm main.go`

Comment: It works but when compiling to wasm I get ```..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\karrick\godirwalk@v1.17.0\readdir_unix.go:58:6: undefined: inoFromDirent``` error

Comment: we're getting the same error.

Comment: @MHSagar  this may be a official issue of packr package , i have updated the answer , please follow the second method ,  if there is any suggestion please let me know .